# Linux permission file

Tags: linux

I am new in Linux machine. I try to copy/paste or create a new folder into a specific folder but I can't make it. As obvious I believe it is the permission in the file.

In order to find the permission I used the following commands and the file I want to copy/paste other files is the shiny-server.

```
stefan@stefan-VirtualBox:~$ ls -l /srv
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan  26 09:53 shiny-server
stefan@stefan-VirtualBox:~$ ls -l /srv/shiny-server
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Jan  26 09:53 index.html -> /opt/shiny-server/samples/welcome.html
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Jan  26 09:53 sample-apps -> /opt/shiny-server/samples/sample-apps
```

Is there any command I should run in the terminal in order to make the shiny-server file available for copy/paste? I am new user and I don't know much so every help will be a push for me not to leave linux.

The command I used in the terminal and the error:

```
cp -a /home/stefan/Downloads/testfile /srv/shiny-server
cp: cannot create directory '/srv/shiny-server/testfile': Permission denied
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, can you provide us the error you got when trying to perform the copy (and the command you are using)

Comment: Try asking on [unix.se]

Comment: You have two options: 1) to lower the permissions of the directory shiny server, which is only writable by the super user (i.e. root) or 2) to raise your rights by issuing commands in the terminal as super user, prepending `sudo ` to your command and entering, if necessary, your users password. Go for the second one. Lowering permissions is generally a bad idea.

Comment: There's no such file operation as `paste`, by the way . It's only copy source to destination

Comment: In addition to what Pierre said, running a web server, or any process with external user interaction, as root is generally a bad idea

Comment: @Jaay thank you. I added what I tried as command and the error.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sudo in front of the copy command or try switching to root user using sudo su command because the file you are trying to access has a root user access only